# How to pass NSMutableArray to UIPickerView?

Tags: soap, nsmutablearray, uipickerview, swift2

I have a query in SOAP service, which returns me a DataSource, that DataSource has two columns per row, how can I bring those columns within the UIPickerView using Swift 2.3?

[image]

I'm using this code to pass the datasource:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

            print(DataSource[row])

    if component == 0 {

          return DataSource[row][IdPessoa] as? String
    } else {

          return DataSource[row][Empresa] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: How are your trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know whats the problem you are facing. But you can edit that line:

**DataSource[row]["IdPessoa"] as? String**

similarly, edit the line in else part.

Otherwise method is correct. Make sure datasource and delegate are set.